# Bufferedgraphics change background to black c#

Tags: c#

I try to do double buffer using BufferedGraphics. When i use BufferedGraphics.Render method background of my image changes to black. Here the simple code, that illustrate my issue

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }
    private void print(Bitmap image, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics graphicsObj = e.Graphics; 
        graphicsObj.DrawImage(image, 60, 10); 
        graphicsObj.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Rectangle rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        PixelFormat pf;
        pf = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, pf);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        g.Clear(Color.Orange);

        BufferedGraphicsContext context = new BufferedGraphicsContext();
        BufferedGraphics buffer = context.Allocate(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width + 20, rect.Height + 20));
        buffer.Render(g);

        print(image, e);
    }
}
```

I expect to see orange rectangle on my screen, but it's black. I can't understand why this happen. Help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer.Render(g)` renders the contents of the buffer *to* the graphics object. This means that the orange color is being overwritten by the empty buffer.

You'll have to choose between using `BufferedGraphicsContext` or creating a buffer yourself (the image).

The following would fix your issue using just the image:

```
...
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, pf);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    g.Clear(Color.Orange);
}

print(image, e);
```

You could also still use `BufferedGraphicsContext`, but you'd have to write the image to its `Graphics` property:

```
print(image, buffer.Graphics); // render your image to the buffer
buffer.Render(e.Graphics); // render the buffer to the paint event graphics
```

By the way, don't `Dispose` the graphics object provided by `Form1_Paint` (you currently do that in the `print()` method.

As a response to your comment, `BufferedGraphicsContext` seems to not support transparency when rendering it to the "main" graphics object, but you can draw transparent images to it correctly. The following example shows how the buffer is filled with a red color, and then a transparent image with a blue line is drawn to it:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    using (BufferedGraphicsContext context = new BufferedGraphicsContext())
    using (BufferedGraphics buffer = context.Allocate(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 120)))
    {
        // Create a bitmap with just a blue line on it
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }

        // Fill a red square
        buffer.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 5, 5, 110, 110);
        // Draw the blue-line image over the red square area
        buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 10, 10);
        // Render the buffer to the underlying graphics
        buffer.Render(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

In the result you can clearly see the blue line from the image over the red color in the background buffer (the red background is not overwritten) and there's a black border around the red rectangle where no background pixels where drawn.

Comment: Can i change background of buffer content? In my work project I add image with transparent background in buffer and when i render it to graphics background changes to black

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's help